# failure time out during tcp connection establishment stage

Tags: tcp, vmware-workstation, citrix, connect

I want to learn  VPX ADC in virtural environment. All the below 3 machines are connected via VMWare Workstation Bridged Network.
Host-Windows 11, IP Address is 192.168.2.60
VM 1 - ubuntu20 ,apache server, IP Address is 192.168.2.56
VM 2 - Citrix ADC Release NS13.1 30.52.nc, NSIP is 192.168.2.31, SNIP, 192.168.2.32

I try to configure waf function for apache service on ubuntu20.I added the load balancing > Server as 192.168.2.56. Then I went and added a Service Group and selected the server as 192.168.2.56 and port 80. What is happening now is that the Service Group shows that the STATE is ENABLED but the EFFECTIVE STATE is DOWN.

I investigated and found that I am unable to ping or telnet on port 80 from ADC (VM 2) to VM 1 and error shown in DOWN state of Service Group is "failure - timeout during tcp connection establishment stage". I am not able to understand why.I can access vm1 and vm2 from the host, but vm2 cannot access my host and vm1. I try to ping my host on the citrix command line interface, but it also failsAlso, the load balancing feature has been enabled in the ADC.

Could you please help me understand what is going wrong in this config?

Comment: please help me!I really need your help.Thanks so much!!